# Mimic default behaviour of row rendering in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, tablecellrenderer, substance

In my Java 7 application I use a Swing `JTable` with two columns. The left column uses a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` where the `setHorizontalAlignment()` is set to centered, whereas the right column uses no specific renderer.

That right column shows each table row in alternating colors by default, which is not the case on the left column with the renderer used. Moreover, when I hover with the mouse over the rows on the right column, then the row under the mouse curser is highlighted when focused, which also isn't the case with the left column.

Is there any (easy) way of mimic the default behaviour of the row rendering (i.e. the alternating colors and the highlighted row) when using a `DefaultTableCellRenderer`?

PS: I am using the Substance L&F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any (easy) way of mimic the default behaviour of the row
>   rendering (i.e. the alternating colors and the highlighted row) when
>   using a DefaultTableCellRenderer?

`Substance` has own `Renderer`s, you should change `XxxXxxRenderer` by add `Substance` before, e.g.
`SubstanceDefaultTableCellRenderer` instead of `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, the same for `JComboBox`, `JList`, `JTree` or `JTableHeader`