# Swing: white color in label foreground is painted as black

Tags: java, swing, paint, look-and-feel, listcellrenderer

Sorry, but I cann't provide the MCVE. I've already found a solution but now I want to understand why the problem happens.
I use the Syntetica L&F with custom (third party) theme. The bug is only with this L&F. I can't reproduce it with Office L&F from JIDE.

I have following code im my extension of `DefaultListCellRenderer`

```
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        //
        // extract text and icon from my business object
        // do nothing with colors
        //
        // here is new code which I added as I got my problem
        //
        if (isSelected) {
            final Color c = list.getSelectionForeground();
            System.out.println("color: " + c + " // " + c.getAlpha() + " // " + c.getTransparency());
            setForeground(c);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Output for the print statement is:

```
color: javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=255,g=255,b=255] // 255 // 1
```

but I get the black foreground for the selected line (wrong)
If I change the last line in `if` statement to:

```
setForeground(new Color(c.getRGB()));
```

I get the correct white foreground for the selected row.

Can somebody explain this behaviour?

**Update**: Looks like a Bug of Synth L&F or Synthetica L&F. If I change the line above to

```
setForeground(new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE));
```

I get the black foreground again.

Comment: did you tried to check APIs, because [most of (good) Custom L&Fs has own XxxXxxRenderer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19739562/714968), and depends of author if is overrode for all JComponents that implements Renderer

Comment: @mKorbel Yes, the synth L&F install the own cell renderer, but I want to use mine because I need to extract icon and text from my business object.

Comment: read licence in docs if you can to modify (clone)their bug_free renderer, don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: @mKorbel Synthetica is a commercial L&F

Comment: again is better, advantage to use commercial product ---> read licence in docs if you can to modify ...., ask for required steps, or exception